# How to get the PID of a program executed in a bash script with remote linux

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, process

I'm on a Mac computer accessing by ssh a linux machine to run simulations. I'm currently running multiple commands in parallel (I put them in background with &), when they finish I extract the files of interest then delete all commands output and redo it.

I wondered if it was possible to check using the PID if those tasks are finished in order to automatically extract the wanted files and launch one more time the exact same command. I'm posting a message here to know to get the PID of a command which is executed through a ssh -c, that is not done by me (as I'm in remote linux).

I tried the solutions shown in [how-to-get-pid-of-just-started-process](https://serverfault.com/questions/205498/how-to-get-pid-of-just-started-process/205563#205563) in order to get the PID, but neither $! nor ssh -c nor jobs -p give me the correct PID. I'm wondering if it doesn't work because I'm on remote access (the command appearing in htop is a ssh -c ...) or I'm just doing things poorly.

Here is my first bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash

./createFiles.sh $1 # create the needed $1 folders

for i in $(seq 1 $1)
do
    cd $i
    myCommand &
    cd ..
done
```

When this one is finished I use :

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(seq 1 $1)
do
    cd $i
    cp output/file.txt ../file_$2_$i.txt # $2 is the number of the run
    cd ..
done

./deleteFiles.sh $2 # delete the needed $1 folders to start anew
```

And then I loop 5 times those two. And I wanted to know if it's possible to loop automatically 5 times and not having me standing in front of my computer.

If any of you have any idea, it would be great :)

P.S: I hope it was clear, english is not my native language hihi

Comment: You can use `$$` to get the PID from inside your script. You could also use `pgrep` to find the PID of a given process name from outside your script.

Comment: I didn't know of `pgrep` existence, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are building GNU Parallel :)

--transfer --return --cleanup is doing exactly what you are trying to do.

Read chapter 8: https://zenodo.org/record/1146014

Comment: Oh ! That's exactly what I needed :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it thanks to @mashuptwice answer (i.e : You can use `$$` to get the PID from inside your script. You could also use `pgrep` to find the PID of a given process name from outside your script. –
mashuptwice Mar 18 at 14:07)

Then using bash `while`, `-s` and `sleep` I arrived where I wanted :D

For the sake of transparency :

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for j in $(seq 1 $2)
do
    ./createFiles.sh $1 # create the needed $1 folders

    for i in $(seq 1 $1)
    do
        cd $i
        myCommand &
        cd ..
    done

    sleep 5 # Wait to be sure that the commands were started

    pgrep -u myUser myCommand > PIDs.txt

    while [ -s PIDs.txt ]
    do
        echo not finished yet
        pgrep -u myUser myCommand > PIDs.txt
        sleep 10
    done
    cat PIDs.txt # Debug print

    ./mvFiles.sh $1 $j # extract the needed files and remove the now useless outputs
    rm PIDs.txt
done
```

Comment: mashuptwice didn't write an _answer_.  You should include the relevant information in your answer, so that it is complete (and continues to make sense in the future when comments get tidied up).